# Front Fender for TREK 3500

Tags: fenders, trek

I have a TREK 3500 Bike, 2015 model, and I've been looking for a compatible front fender. The standard strap-ons don't work, as the front fork is also the suspension.

[image: The TREK 3500]

Comment: Specific product recommendations are off topic here, look for one that snaps into the bottom of the steerer tube. Try googling "26 inch steerer tube mudguard"